# AutomationProperties in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, ui-automation

Can anyone give an example as to how AutomationProperties.LiveSettings work?

I have been working on a WPF application and I want a Text Block to be made live. In Html its easy to do, but using an aria-live tag, however I have been struggling to do the same in WPF.

Comment: I have a textblock which changes after a certain time. I want narrator to read it when it changes. So I was thinking of using the concept of LiveRegion.

Comment: So you want to change the contents of a text box after a certain time and instead of just setting the text you want to use automation for that purpose? From within the same application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutomationProperties.LiveSetting cannot be used in WPF. 
It can be used with XAML only for developing windows store app or mobile app. In case of a store/phone app, a different library of AutomationProperties is used which supports the usage of LiveSettings. In case of WPF app, there is a different library of AutomationProperties which doesn't have the LiveSettings property.

Comment: [It can be used in WPF as of .NET Framework 4.7.1](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/ceb96832217d7c5b4e494512d104a8588635771a/docs/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility.md#windows-presentation-foundation-wpf-1)